# INotifyPropertyChanged vs BindableObject vs ObservableObject in Xamarin.Forms/MAUI

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-community-toolkit

I have a hard time understanding the difference between those 3 things when creating a project using Xamarin.Forms or MAUI. I know what these are - `INotifyPropertyChanged` is an interface you need to implement when you want to use bindings in XAML, `BindableObject` is Xamarin.Forms class that implements said interface and `ObservableObject` is a class found in Xamarin Community Toolkit that also implements that interface. I just don't really understand the differences between them (especially the latter two) and when you would use any of them? I have read different tutorials and they all say different things - that you need to implement the interface yourself (so your viewmodel implements it), that your viewmodel needs to inherit from `BindableObject`, or - if you're using Xamarin Community Toolkit (which you probably should use/are using) - inherit from `ObservableObject`. But - like I said - why should you use any of the solutions mentioned above over the others?

If you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface Visual Studio (or ReSharper extension, I'm not sure which one) automatically implements the method it needs to and adds this code:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void PropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

But it makes your code longer/uglier, so I understand why you would want to only inherit from a class that already implements that interface. But then why some people say you should always implement it yourself? Is there a difference when you implement it yourself or inherit from a class that already implements it? Also, if you decide to inherit from a class - why use either one over the other one? [The documentation of Xamarin.Forms is quite good in this regard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject?view=xamarin-forms), but it doesn't acknowledge the existence of Xamarin Community Toolkit and [the Xamarin Community Toolkit documentation doesn't answer my question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.communitytoolkit.objectmodel.observableobject?view=xamarin-community-toolkit-sdk) and doesn't say why you should use their `ObservableObject` over Xamarin.Form's built-in `BindableObject`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your confusion is stemming from the difference between **Bindable** and **Observable**.

You're mostly correct about [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-6.0). It's the abstract concept of a value changing, not the concrete implementation of that change. It's not just used for XAML though, it can be used for anything. But what do I mean by that?

Different parts of a system will care about why a value is changed for different reasons. A class that sits and silently logs data to a text file based on the value of something changing, is very different to a class that updates an application's user interface when something changes.

INotifyPropertyChanged is merely a *mechanism* to facilitate that change notification, it's nothing more.

Circling back to the difference between [ObservableObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.communitytoolkit.objectmodel.observableobject?view=xamarin-community-toolkit-sdk) and [BindableObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobject?view=xamarin-forms), they're simply for different use cases.

Take a look at the documentation I linked to above. See how many methods exist on the BindableObject class? Notice how [OnPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobject.onpropertychanged?view=xamarin-forms#xamarin-forms-bindableobject-onpropertychanged(system-string)) is just one of many methods on the BindableObject, but on [ObservableObject it's one of only two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.communitytoolkit.objectmodel.observableobject?view=xamarin-community-toolkit-sdk#methods)?

BindableObject is used as a base class for *elements*. Changing the state of a button to disable it when it's clicked, for example. Or updating the text value of a Label in response to something changing.

ObservableObject can be used as a base class *for anything* that needs to notify some other class about a value change. As you correctly pointed out, it's to stop you needing to write that boilerplate INotifyPropertyChanged implementation all the time.

There's much more to this subject, but I don't want to bombard you with a huge amount of information.

If you're looking for some real world examples, study how the [MVVM design pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm) leverages the concept of classes communicating changes to one another.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer really helped me and cleared the confusion. Especially thank you for providing useful links. But I have one more question though, just to be sure - does this mean that my ViewModels should inherit from `ObservableObject`, as there is no need to inherit from `BindableObject`? Also - does this mean that if I follow the MVVM pattern there's no need for me to ever inherit from `BindableObject`, because the code-behind files for XAML already inherit from `ContentPage` (which indirectly inherits from `BindableObject`)?

Comment: Not a problem, thanks for marking it as accepted. I'm trying to get a reputation for providing great Xamarin help to people here :)

The answer is your question is "Yes. MOST of the time". A good rule of thumb is "ViewModels are ObservableObjects, Views are Pages, Elements on Views are BindableObjects".

Comment: Excellent answer. Minor correction re *"Views are Pages"*: Pages and Views are VisualElements. All Elements are BindableObjects.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks! Fair correction as well. I was trying not to get bogged down into the nitty gritty, but a few months removed from writing this answer, I think it's right to mention.

Answer (score 3):

There is some confusion I think about the different classes:

- Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject is meant to be used to create something like a custom view with bindable properties. It also implements INotifyPropertyChanged, but I don't think you should use it for a ViewModel.
- The ObservableObject from the community toolkit can be used as a base class for any class you like to use with data binding, you don't need to implement it yourself.
- If you have some custom requirements for handling the OnPropertyChanged, you do need to implement the interface yourself, but if you just want to have default behaviour, ObservableObject is perfectly fine.